# Is there any program which take questions randomly from PDF file?

Tags: pdf

I just want to ask if there is some kind of kind of program in which I provide a PDF file with full of questions and that program selects from them randomly to ask me like a exam?!

For example: I am a pilot and I got a question bank (all mcqs) in PDF file. Now I want to insert that file in the desired program and have it randomly give me questions.

Comment: Mohammed - the first problem is that not all pdfs that display as text actually have that same text in them as text, e.g.: Scanned documents often have no, or very badly OCRed, text - just pictures of the pages.

Comment: Please post a sample PDF file, otherwise we can't tell whether it is possible or not.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: If there is 1 question per page, then I guess OCR is not needed :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - in that case all that is needed is to randomly display one page - a rather different question.

Comment: Which operating system? Free, or do you have a budget? The more information that you give, the better we can help you.

Comment: Do the questions have to be in PDF format? Are they pure text, or will they have diagrams? If they are in, or can be converted to, then the answer is the classic Fortune Cookie program http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_%28Unix%29 which is also available for Windows

Comment: @Mohammed, Do you mind, Can we have a sample of the pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this StackOverflow question: [Extracting one page from pdf file using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382299/extracting-one-page-from-pdf-file-using-itext), it contains a small code snippet that "burst" a PDF:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("resources/Abdomen.pdf");
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    reader.close();
    String path;
    PdfStamper stamper;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        reader = new PdfReader("resources/abdomen.pdf");
        reader.selectPages(String.valueOf(i));
        path = String.format("results/abdomen/p-%s.pdf", i);
        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,new FileOutputStream(path));
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

"Bursting" means: to split a PDF with X pages into X PDFs with a single page. If you only need a single page, you don't need to loop over the different pages, you can just use the code inside the `for`-loop to select one page.

The syntax of the parameter of the `selectPages()` method is explained in the answer to this question: [PDF Page re-ordering using itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600040/pdf-page-re-ordering-using-itext).

All of this is done in Java using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/), but if you prefer C#, we also have iTextSharp. There is a free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) that contains an abundance of code samples in Java as well as in C#.

Comment: A great solution if this were programmers. Maybe not so good for S/W recs?

Comment: @Mawg For a question as specific as this one, one should not expect a software solution that works "out-of-the-box" in spite of the fact that the amount of programming that is needed to meet the requirement may be limited.

Comment: But has the OP indicated in any way that he is a programmer? If so, I would expect him to either take a stab at it and post to http://stackoverflow.com/ if he has problems, or post to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ for general implementation advice.  AFIK, this site **is** for recommending "out of the box" s/w, or for stating that there probably isn't any - not for telling people how to code.

Comment: Where does it says so? Software is software is software. When I think of software, I don't think of Office, Acrobat, Windows,... Those are applications, OSs,... When I think of software, I think of code, libraries, software components.

Comment: I think of those too **because I am a programmer**, and I also think of off-the shelf solutions. But how many users of this site do we imagine to be programmers? I don't want to argue with you, so let's take this to meta - maybe we can even introduce a `source-code-welcome` tag? :-)

Comment: I'd say it's welcome because even if it doesn't help the OP directly, there may be other readers who use the source code and turn it into a ready-made tool.

Comment: A valid point. Let's see what others think ... http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/is-source-code-an-acceptable-answer